# Инициализация объекта std::initializer_list (С++)

Tags: c++, инициализация, стандарт

У меня есть функция, которая принимает в аргументах `std::initializer_list`

```
void CEventManager::sendEvent(EEventType eEventType, const std::initializer_list<CEventArg> &rcEventArgs) noexcept
{
    // Найти список (вектор) в ассоциативном массиве (map) По типу события
    auto it = m_cEventHandlers.find(eEventType);
    // Если найден
    if (it != m_cEventHandlers.end())
    {
        // Пройтись по всем элементам списка (слушателям) и вызывать функцию обработки события
        for (auto& handler : it->second)
        {
            handler->handleEvent(eEventType, rcEventArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

Я использую именно `initializer_list` а не `vector`, поскольку где-то вычитал что это очень быстрый и эффективный контейнер, который позволяет реализовать передачу переменного кол-ва аргументов.

И у меня возникла необходимость вызвать эту функцию, инициализировав аргумент rcEventArgs при помощи вектора. То есть у меня есть вектор со списком аргументов, который я бы хотел передать.

```
void CEventManager::update([[maybe_unused]] float fDelta)
{
    // Заблокировать чтение/запись массива отложенных событий
    m_cMutexQueuedEvents.lock();

    // Последнее отложенное событие
    auto& rsEventInfo = m_cQueuedEvents.back();
    
    // Список аргументов события
    auto cArgList = std::initializer_list<CEventArg>(/*Как добавить сюда мои аргументы из вектора динамически???*/);
    
    // Отправить
    this->sendEvent(rsEventInfo.m_eEventType, cArgList);
    
    // Удалить отложенное событие из списка
    m_cQueuedEvents.pop_back();

    // Разблокировать чтение/запись массива отложенных событий
    m_cMutexQueuedEvents.unlock();
}
```

Но так и не нашел внятного ответа, можно ли, и если можно, то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак нельзя. Вместо `std::initializer_list` лучше взять `std::span<const CEventArg>`.

Вектор в такой параметр можно передавать напрямую.

Список в фигурных скобках напрямую не получится, вместо него можно `std::array<CEventArg>{...}`. Или добавить вторую перегрузку с параметром `initializer_list`, из которой вызывать основную перегрузку, передавая в этот параметр `{l.begin(), l.end()}`.